# tracking the tickets against developer

Tags: testing, jira

I am working on java development where issues have been assigned to me, as we are using JIRA 5 in which ticket's have been logged and similarly QA team also create a ticket to test the issues corresponding to our dev, now i want to know let say QA team mean testers are tesing my dev item and they found a defect against it so they create another ticket and link to it my dev ticket so i want to know is there any setting that we can done in ticket to track that against which developer how many issues that QA team have tested how many tickets they have raised and how many were real tickets and how many were rejected by developer itself as QA team have not tested correctly, is that configuration can be achieved in JIRA 5 or any freeware tool to test that.

So basically i want to know the statististics of a developer.

Comment: By "jira" and "jiras" you mean tickets/issues?

Comment: Use the built-in JQL search functionality. You can search on about everything, eg reporter, assignee, project, ... If you save the search, you can add it to a Dashboard as a filter gadget also.

Comment: @Koshinae can you please explain in detail pls

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on these manuals and tutorials:

1. http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14/
2. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching
3. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+the+Filter+Results+Gadget